# Cancel asyntask if app goes background and is killed if app comes foreground resume ayntask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have been downloading images and saving them to sdcard in a async task if the app goes background and is killed downloading will be incomplete so am cancelling the async task in onstop and deleting the images downloaded so that there will not be any incomplete images.The problem occurs when i press home button and resume back i have restart the cancelled async task here.Can anyone help me in solving this

Answer (score 0):

Do not use onStop(). Pause the task in onPause(), resume it in onResume().

Answer (score 0):

The `cancel()` method of the `AsyncTask` class will set the cancel flag. You can check it in your `AsyncTask` by using the `isCancelled()` method to decide what to do in such a case.

In `onStop()`, you can `cancel()`. When the cancel happens, you can save whatever processing was donw to some persistent storage. Then, re-execute the `AsyncTask` in `onRestart()` or `onResume()`. Needless to say, your coding logic must accommodate all this.

Instead of deleting the downloaded images, why not save the URLs of the images in SQLite and mark the ones downloaded? When the task restarts, download just the ones that havent been downloaded. This will save bandwidth.

As for the home button, you cannot not override it's behavior. Instead, use the [`onUserLeaveHint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint()) method:

> Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is about to
>   go into the background as the result of user choice. For example, when
>   the user presses the Home key, onUserLeaveHint() will be called